# Running Linux shell on OS X

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix

I want some applications to run on my OS X. But they cant be ran due to they are only for Linux. How can I have a Linux shell on my OS X? I mean how can I have a seperate Linux shell and  a OS X terminal on OS X?

Comment: the osx terminal runs bash. the linux terminal is bash. They are the same unless you are somewhat atypical and pick zsh or csh one one of the few others. What do you mean by "only for linux". Certainly there are differences between the two operating systems, but if you're talking about shell scripts they are largely the same.

Comment: Aha thank you. How can I have a Linux kernel on my OS X? I dont want dual booting. @bryan-oakley

Comment: Mac OS X has different commands from those found on Linux.  It also doesn't have features such as the `/proc` file system that Linux has.  If your shell scripts use portable commands portably, you should be OK.  If they're tied to Linux-only functionality, they'll fail.  You can use VMWare or similar systems to run Linux in a guest o/s on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your use specific use case:

- To run *GNU* utilities (as found on Linux systems) *alongside* the mostly BSD-based utilities *on macOS*, install them via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh); note that installing *alongside* entails that the GNU utility names are `g`-prefixed to avoid shadowing the stock macOS utilities; e.g., GNU `ls` is installed as `gls`; also note that macOS's Bash is still `v3.x` and will remain on that version for licensing reasons:

  - `brew install coreutils` ... most of the GNU utilities (installed `g`-prefixed)
  - `brew install gawk` ... GNU Awk (installed as `gawk`)
  - `brew install findutils` ... the `find` utliity (installed as `gfind`)
  - `brew install gnu-sed` ... GNU Sed (installed as `gsed`)
- To run commands in an *isolated*, bona fide *Linux*  environment *inside a VM* (using Bash `v4.x` and above), install [Docker](http://www.docker.com/) and then install, e.g., an Ubuntu image (`docker pull ubuntu`).

  - With the Docker environment loaded (open application `Docker QuickStart Terminal.app`), you can then run `docker run -it ubuntu bash` to enter an interactive Linux Bash shell.

Comment: thanks. Docker way is a good option for me.